# $\mathbb{C}\{X\}^\chi$ a $G$-stable subspace of $\mathbb{C}\{X\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field with $q$ elements, and let $G = SL_2(\mathbb{F})$. The group $G$ acts on the set $X := \mathbb{F}^2 \setminus \{0\}$, the complement of the origin. For any group homomorphism $\chi: \mathbb{F}^\times \to S^1 \subset \mathbb{C}^\times$, in $\mathbb{C}\{X\}$, we define a subspace$$\mathbb{C}\{X\}^\chi := \{f \in \mathbb{C}\{X\} : f(z \cdot x) = \chi(z) \cdot f(x), \text{ }\forall\,z \in \mathbb{F}^\times\}.$$My question is, is $\mathbb{C}\{X\}^\chi$ a $G$-stable subspace of $\mathbb{C}\{X\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f \in \mathbb{C}\{X\}^\chi$ and let $g \in G$. The group $G$ acts on the right on $\mathbb{C}\{X\}$ by $(f \cdot g)(x) = f(g \cdot x)$. For all $z \in \mathbb{F}^\times$,
$$(f \cdot g)(z \cdot x) = f(g \cdot (z \cdot x)) = f(z \cdot (g \cdot x)) = \chi(z) \cdot f(g \cdot x) = \chi(z) (f \cdot g)(x),$$
because $g$ and $z$ commute ($z$ is simply multiplication by a scalar...). So $f \cdot g \in \mathbb{C}\{X\}^\chi$ again, and thus $\mathbb{C}\{X\}^\chi$ is $G$-stable.